# mysql backup and restore to a table with different column names

Tags: mysql, restore

I have a table - customers_old . I want to copy all the data from this table, so I will use mysqldump.

I need to restore data into a table , customers_new, which has column names different from customers_old table.

How do I do this?

INSERT..SELECT is only for manually copying each row?

Kindly advise

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple ctas (Create Table AS) operation:

```
CREATE TABLE customers_new AS SELECT col1 AS new_col1, col2 AS new_col2 FROM customers_old
```

By aliasing your old columns you can change the column names in the new table.

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html

Answer (score 3):

To expand on PMV's answer:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (column1_new, column2_new, ...) 
  SELECT column1_old, column2_old FROM oldtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either edit the column and tables names in your sql dump file, or import the new table then do a INSERT SELECT from the old table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly, unless you manually hack up the dump file to change the column names in there. One option would be to load the dump into a temporary database/table and then do some ALTER TABLE queries to rename the columns to whatever you want. Or you could do the INSERT/SELECT, but the you'd end up with double the data (new renamed table/fields + old original table/fields).

Comment: Alter table copies the data into a new table and then deletes the old table, so there's less difference in that approach than you'd think.

Comment: only if you're changing data types. renaming columns doesn't do that.

Comment: I guess hacking the dump file is the way to go then. I will post back once I have something working